# Can't correctly parse cisco cli command output

Tags: python, regex, parsing

I am trying to parse Cisco `show ip interface vrf all` command output from txt file by reading line by line in loop.

The output is:

```
IP Interface Status for VRF "default"
loopback1, Interface status: protocol-up/link-up/admin-up, iod: 212,
IP address: 10.1.0.1, IP subnet: 10.1.0.0/30
...

Ethernet1/1, Interface status: protocol-up/link-up/admin-up, iod: 278,
  IP address: 10.0.0.1, IP subnet: 10.0.0.0/30

IP Interface Status for VRF "TEST"
Vlan99, Interface status: protocol-up/link-up/admin-up, iod: 147,
  IP address: 172.16.0.1, IP subnet: 172.16.0.0/24
  ...
Vlan888, Interface status: protocol-up/link-up/admin-up, iod: 115,
  IP address: 172.16.1.1, IP subnet: 172.16.1.0/24
...
```

And so on.

I need to extract only VRF that have VLAN and subnet.
For example from this output I should have variables in every iteration:

```
vrf -> vlan -> subnet (TEST -> 99 -> 172.16.0.0/24)
vrf -> vlan -> subnet (TEST -> 888 -> 172.16.1.0/24)
```

But I don't need info from `default vrf` because it has no VLans.

I wrote some regular expressions to find this info:

```
   vrf = re.findall( r'VRF "(.*)"', line)
   vlan = re.findall( r'Vlan(\d+)', line)
   subnet= re.findall( r'IP address.*subnet:\s(.*)$', line)
```

But I do not know how to ignore VRFs with no vlans.

Comment: What's the end result you want to get?

Comment: I need insert all vrf's and their vlan numbers and subnets to mysql while iterating through lines.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this expression:

```
^(Vlan\d+).+[\n\r]
.+?subnet:\ (.+)
```

---

In `Python` code:

```
import re
rx = re.compile("""
    ^(Vlan\d+).+[\n\r] # capture Vlan, followed by digits at the beginning of line
    .+?subnet:\ (.+)   # match anything lazily, followed by subnet and capture the address
    """,re.MULTILINE|re.VERBOSE)

for match in rx.finditer(your_string_here):
    print match.group(1) # Vlan99
    print match.group(2) # the subnet ip
```

---

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/kZ8jA6/1).

Comment: It is working, but I need extract vrf name also. I tried to change this expression: VRF\ "(.*)"[\n\r]
Vlan(\d+).+[\n\r]
.+?subnet:\ (.+)  but it find only vrf and first vlan and first subnet, but there are two or more vlans on VRF

Comment: @Jegor: Please provide an exact output then (edit your original question, that is).